# App built with NextJs stops running when navigating away from it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, render

I have built a simple timer app using NextJS, in  React.
I have hosted this app on Render.
My problem is, when I navigate away from the website, minimize or go to another tab, the timer stops running.

Not sure where to look for an answer, any help appreciated.

I hosted this as a 'web service' in render.

Here is link to the github repo
https://github.com/LachiePD/latest-timer-app

Comment: are you using canvas and requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: No, just displaying a value held in state, then updating that state through a setTimeout()